# How to Select By Location with matching attribute?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, select-by-attribute, select-by-location

I have a whole bunch of overlapping polygons (buffers), I want to select with points only those poly's which:

1. the point falls within; and
2. the poly attribute matches the point attribute

What would be the best way to do this selection, perhaps with ModelBuilder? (using ArcGIS Desktop 9.3.1)

Answer (score 5):

I am thinking you could do a spatial join of the points to your buffered polys which will join the attributes of both together, then you can select back the points that have matching ColumnX and ColumnY values.
You can do just a Intersect or Identify as well, all three will give you a very similar result to append the attributed from the poly to the point then you can extract the specifics.

Comment: thanks all, i ended up doing the spatial join, thanks for the assist

Answer (score 1):

[Intersecting](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Intersect%20%28Analysis%29) the point and buffer polygons should work. By default, the output points would get the attributes of the polygon they've intersected with. You can then query the points for the poly attribute.